# If an exception pointer is thrown, can EXPECT_THROW in google test capture this exception?

Tags: googletest

For example, I have a code like:

```
TEST_F(Testmyexception, testthrownexception)
{
  EXPECT_THROW(throw new myexception(), myexception);
}
```

After compiling and running, it gives an error: Actual: it throws a different type.

Does anynone know the answer?

Thanks,

Comment: If Fraser's answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

You're throwing a pointer to a `myexception`, so you have to expect a pointer in the check:

```
EXPECT_THROW(throw new myexception(), myexception*);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want:

```
EXPECT_THROW(throw std::underflow_error(""), std::underflow_error);
```

BTW the syntax to throw an instance of myexception is:

```
throw myexception();
```

the "new" keyword should not be used here.